# "Сверкнула молния(,) послышался резкий звук грома". Запятая или тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

В данном случае лучше поставить после "молния" тире или запятую? Будет ли соответствовать нормам наличие в данном случае запятой?

Answer (score 5):

Попробую использовать  названия для лучшего понимания ответа

**1. Откуда взялось это предложение**

Я обычно это проверяю в надежде найти контекст – а вдруг классик какой?

Но нет, это предложение из упражнения, приведенного в учебнике: *Дождь стучал по крыше и трепал листья. **Сверкнула молния, и послышался резкий удар грома.** Дорога шла на подъём, и машинист с трудом затормозил пассажирский состав*. И т.д.

Тема упражнения понятна: разбирается отличие  ССП от однородных членов. Но автор вопроса в заданном предложении  просто убрал союз И, и у него получилось   получилось БСП. Но в принципе ничего не меняется, будем решать БСП.

**2. Решение**

***Сверкнула молния, послышался резкий звук грома.***

В БСП излагается последовательность событий, поэтому ставится **запятая**. Интонация перечислительная, предложения считаются однородными (независимыми).

Для постановки тире особых причин нет. Почему? Причинно-следственные связи мы обозначаем далеко не всегда, а только при необходимости их подчеркнуть. Если смотреть на это с философской точки зрения, то вся наша жизнь – это сплошная причинно-следственная цепочка разных событий. Вот автор и решает, есть ли смысл ему эту связь обозначать в данном конкретном случае.

И правильно решает, что нет такого смысла. За ударом молнии рано или поздно последует гром, но с определенным интервалом. Автор наблюдает: вот молния сверкнула, вот прозвучал гром, довольно резкий.

**3. Когда мы ставим тире**

Для это нужны  причины. Большой неожиданности здесь  не может быть, и тире буде скорее присоединительным: автор сообщает нам свои **особые** впечатления. Это  или очень сильный удар грома, или совсем короткое время между молнией и громом, если до этого он звучал отдаленно.

Но тогда **запись должна быть другой**, например:

*Сверкнула молния  – оглушительный  удар грома будто расколол небо.*

*Сверкнула молния –  резкий удар грома  прозвучал  почти сразу же.*

Очень надеюсь, что теперь меня все поняли, а  какое правило смотреть – неизвестно.

Comment: Я вот не очень понял, зачем переделывать предложение? Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на примеры у Розенталя к 1-му пункту правила. По-вашему, они корректны?

Comment: Извините, Игорь, а куда (где) смотреть-то?

Comment: @Sharon Из Вашего ответа: _Тема понятна: отличие ССП от однородных членов._ Извините, но ничего не понятно. **Сверкнула молния, послышался резкий звук грома.** Здесь нет ни сложносочиненного предложения, ни однородных членов.

Answer (score 4):

Оснований для тире не видно потому, что здесь описана простая последовательность событий, разнесённых во времени (звуки грома всегда доносятся с задержкой на пару секунд).

> Сверкнула молния, (затем) послышался резкий звук грома.

Вот если бы после "молнии" было пояснение (что это означало), понадобилось бы тире:

> Сверкнула молния - начиналась гроза.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, запятую поставить можно, но тире более предпочтительно, на мой взгляд.

***Сверкнула молния — послышался резкий звук грома.***

В вашем примере едва ли можно проследить простую последовательность событий, их перечисление. Здесь имеет место быть **резкая смена событий**, а также прослеживается **причинно-следственная связь**. Наличие этих факторов требует постановки тире.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/51.htm#%D0%B7_03

> Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении, распадающемся на две части, ставится:
> **1) Если во второй части содержится неожиданное присоединение, указание на быструю смену событий (между обеими частями можно вставить союз и)**, например: 
> Иван Иванович подошел к воротам, загремел щеколдой – изнутри поднялся собачий лай (Гоголь); **Вдруг дверь каморки быстро распахнулась – вся челядь тотчас кубарем скатилась с лестницы (Тургенев)**; Игнат спустил курок – ружье дало осечку (Чехов); Упадет луч солнца на траву – вспыхнет трава изумрудом и жемчугом (Горький); Метелица был уже совсем близко от костра – вдруг конское ржанье раздалось во тьме (Фадеев); Еще выстрел – кучер выронил вожжи и тихо сполз под колеса (Шукшин);
>
> **2) Если вторая часть заключает в себе следствие, вывод из того, о чем говорится в первой части (между частями можно вставить слова поэтому, тогда)**, например: Я умираю – мне не к чему лгать (Тургенев); Не было никакой возможности уйти незаметно – он вышел открыто, будто идет на двор, и шмыгнул в огород (Фадеев); **Достав из кармана одновременно и спички, и зажигалку, Крайнев зажег шнуры – они вспыхнули (Попов).**

Тире в вашем предложении позволит подчеркнуть **внезапность** появления грома, его **близость**, а не само его наличие. К тому же как дыма без огня не бывает, так и грома без молнии: резкий звук грома является следствием молнии, а не независимым событием — тире эту связь выделит, не даст ей скрыться.

**Таким образом, я всецело за тире!**

Comment: Разве гром является следствием или причиной молнии? Это разные внешние проявления одного и того же (грозы). Едва ли после молнии можно "тотчас" услышать гром - из-за известного различия скоростей света и звука. Даже фраза с грамматически уместным тире ("- и тут же послышался гром") неестественна по смыслу.